# Multiple grouped differences in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-regression

### Goal

Currently I only report means for calculations which I show below, but I would like to add confidence intervals.

If I have the data in the correct format it would not be had for me to use linear regression`lm()` to calculate estimated grouped differences and their intervals, but I am having difficulty getting the data in the correct format.

Here is some data:

### fake data

```
> set.seed(909)
> d2017pre <- tibble(n = rnorm(25, mean = 1100, sd = 10),period = "pre", year = 2017)
> d2016pre <- tibble(n = rnorm(25, mean = 1500, sd = 10),period = "pre", year = 2016)
> d2017post <- tibble(n = rnorm(25, mean = 1000, sd = 10),period = "post", year = 2017)
> d2016post <- tibble(n = rnorm(25, mean = 900, sd = 10),period = "post", year = 2016)
> df <- bind_rows(d2017pre,d2016pre,d2017post,d2016post)


> df %>% group_by(year,period) %>% summarise(mean(n))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups: year [?]
   year period `mean(n)`
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1  2016 post         899
2  2016 pre         1498
3  2017 post         999
4  2017 pre         1104
```

### Background

These are the three calculations I routinely do.

```
> # pre - post 2016
> pp16 <- 1498 - 899
> pp16
[1] 599
> 
> # pre - post 2017
> pp17 <-1100 - 999
> pp17
[1] 101
> 
> # net of control: pp2016 - pp2017 
> noc <- pp16 - pp17
> noc
[1] 498
```

The questions this answers is:

1. What was the difference between the `pre` and `post` period in `2016` or `2017`
2. Was `2017`s pre/post difference greater than `2016`s pre/post difference.

I would like to answer these questions not just with estimates but also with confidence intervals. As mentioned above, I am planing on using `lm()` to get the confidence intervals of differences, but I am having difficulty getting the data in the correct format.

I believe that this will require two data sets. One for the difference of the periods in the year and one for the differences of the differences (net of control). This leads to the following questions.

### Questions

1. How can I calculated the differences of `n` grouped by `period` and `year`?
2. How can I calculate the differences of differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get the differences using another `group_by`.

```
diffs <- df %>% 
  group_by(year, period) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(n)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(diff = diff(mean))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   year  diff
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2016   599
2  2017   105
```

The difference of the differences is similar, then (bad namespace maybe..)

```
diff(rev(diffs$diff))

[1] 493.8846
```

For the regression, you actually do not need to alter your dataframe - the data is needed to calculate the effects. I think (but not sure if I understand correctly) you are looking for a model with interaction effect?

E.g.,

```
m1 <- lm(n ~ period + factor(year) + period*factor(year), data = df)
summary(m1)
```

Note how the interaction effect is basically that difference